# MvcSiteMapProvider MVC5 auto generate sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I am trying to auto generate the sitemap, I am using the following
Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="WebUI" />
        <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
        <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SiteMapFileName" value="~/Mvc.sitemap"/>

    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ExcludeAssembliesForScan" value=""/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value=""/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_AttributesToIgnore" value=""/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_CacheDuration" value="5"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ControllerTypeResolverAreaNamespacesToIgnore" value=""/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibiltyProvider" value=""/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_VisibilityAffectsDescendants" value="true"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableLocalization" value="true"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSitemapsXml" value="true"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableResolvedUrlCaching" value="true"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFile" value="true"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeRootNodeFromSiteMapFile" value="true"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFileNestedDynamicNodeRecursion" value="false"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseTitleIfDescriptionNotProvided" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Controller:

```
        [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Healthcare", Key = "Healthcare", ParentKey = "Home")]
        public ActionResult Healthcare (){..}
```

The sitemap MVC.sitemap does not update? 
I changed the following line to ture

```
 <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true"/>
```

Got this error:

```
Not all configured nodes could be paired with a parent node. Check your parent keys to ensure that a node with a corresponding key exists in the SiteMap. Note that the match is case sensitive.
SiteMapCacheKey: 'sitemap://localhost/'
Orphaned Nodes:
ParentKey: 'Home' | Controller: 'Home' | Action: 'Healthcare' | Area: '' | URL: '/Home/Healthcare' | Key: 'Healthcare' | Source: 'MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute'
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way to automatically generate the SiteMap. Each node must be manually configured using one of the available node definition options ([XML file](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-XML), [`[MvcSiteMapNode]` attribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-.NET-attributes), [dynamic node providers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider), or ISiteMapNodeProvider).

The primary reason for this is that MVC has no pre-defined hierarchy of pages, only controllers and actions, so you would end up with a SiteMap object that has a root node with all of the pages just below it. It would also not be possible to auto detect all of the possible values for action parameters. A scanned SiteMap like that would be useless for site navigation in most cases.

That said, if you only want to create an XML sitemap to submit to search engines (which is flat anyway), or you can think of a way to tell MvcSiteMapProvider how to nest the key/parent key relationships for navigation, you could implement ISiteMapNodeProvider and scan for controllers and actions yourself (you could use the [ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Builder/ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider.cs) as a guide).

**Some Pointers for Your Existing Configuration:**

Setting the `MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes` setting to true is required when using `[MvcSiteMapNode]` attribute, so that part you got right.

However, you have the `MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan` and `MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer` settings defined twice.

The error indicates there is no node in your SiteMap that has a key named "Home", so it doesn't know where in the hierarchy to put the `[MvcSiteMapNode]` you have configured.

Since you have set both `MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFile` and `MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeRootNodeFromSiteMapFile` to true, you must define your root node in the Mvc.sitemap file, and give it an explicit key "Home" (if that is what you intended, anyway).

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" key="Home">
    <!-- If you have any additional nodes you want to define in XML, put them here -->
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

If you only want to use `[MvcSiteMapNode]` for configuring your nodes (with no XML configuration), you should set the `MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFile` setting to false and delete the Mvc.sitemap and MvcSiteMapProvider.xsd files. In this case, you will need to define a root node  (a node with no parent key) using `[MvcSiteMapNode]`.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Home", Key = "Home")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, very helpful.  When I edited the MVC.sitemap manually, it works however canonicalUrl works only for the first two lines.  Is there any place I need to change the number of lines.  I am following your example http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/10/mvcsitemapprovider-4-seo-features.  Excellent tool by the way, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "canonicalUrl works only for the first two lines". Do note that using a canonicalKey is usually a better approach because it will dynamically synchronize the URL of the canonical (authoritive) node if its configuration changes. The canonicalUrl will only work when the URL is exactly what is generated from the canonical node.

Comment: Thank you, I did try canocicalKey, no luck; I have posted my code in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895766/mvcsitemapprovider-mvc5-canonicalurl.  I think, I don't understand how the xml file is structured.